# Turn each line of a text file into an array c

Tags: c, arrays, file, text, line

I'm trying to take input from a text file, and then reverse each line, and output back into a different text file. For some reason, the program only dos this for the first line, and does not move onto the second line. I don't get this because it should keep going until it hits EOF.

Comment: `while ( (temp=getchar()) != EOF )` allows you to remove three copies of `temp=getchar();`. You might also want to add a `putchar('\n');` before the return in the `reverse` function.

Comment: Also the code you posted will read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`. Is this your real program?

Comment: @iharob He's using I/O redirection to read and write files

Comment: I see now the way he is running the program.

Comment: yes, I'm using file redirection.

Comment: Are you sure the second line of your input file ends with a newline? You only print out the reversed line when you read a newline, so you won't print the last line if it doesn't.

Comment: The function you use is defined as `int getchar();` so you need to use `int temp` and not `char temp`. Otherwise you can't tell the difference between the byte value `0xFF` and the flag `EOF`.

Comment: Your program works for me: http://ideone.com/xVDsZ9

Comment: `for (a = 80; a >= 0; a--)` breaks `array[80]`. It should be `for (a = 79; a >= 0; a--)`

Comment: Thanks Barmar, you were right, the second line in my test file did not have a newline character. I'll have to fix that.

Comment: And thanks Weather Vane, That fixes a problem I was having where it prints a randon nonsese character before the reversed array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file doesn't end with a newline, you'll never print the last line, because you only call `reverse(array)` when you read the newline character.

You can solve this by calling it again after the `while` loop is done.

```
int  main() {
    char temp;
    char  array[80] = "";
    int count = 0;
    temp = getchar();  //Start on first Character
    while (temp != EOF) {   //loop through the entire file
        if (temp == '\n') {  //If it is the end of a line
            reverse(array);   //Print out the reversed line
            memset(array,0,80);  //clear the array
            count = 0;  //reset count
            temp = getchar(); //Advance getchar
        }
        else {  //If it is not the end of the line
            array[count] = temp;  //Store the char in the array
            count++;   //advance count
            temp = getchar();   //advance getchar
        }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        reverse(array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```